# FTP Script - Put images in year/date folders

Tags: ssh, centos, sh

I have the following script that I am running on Centos which should connect to an external FTP and upload to a directory.

The directory is dependent on the date and needs to dynamically fetch the year and week number.

```
#!/bin/sh
USER3='USERNAME'
PASSWD3='PASSWORD'
YEAR= date "+%G"
WEEK= date "+%V"
ftp -n -i HOST.com <<SCRIPT3
user $USER3 $PASSWD3
binary
cd htdocs/uploads/$YEAR/$WEEK/
bin
mput *.jpg
quit
SCRIPT3
```

If I run the script I get this as a response:

```
# bash test.sh
2014
28
```

So it looks like it is displaying the year and week number but not implementing them in to the folder location part of the script.

How do i get the year/date to echo in to the URL of the folder?

Comment: you need to capture the output of the `date` cmds using shell feature "command-substition". You are close, but try `YEAR=$(date "+%G")`, (fixing all such assignments), and if that doesn't work, convert the $( and closing ) to a \` (back-tic) char. GOod luck.

Comment: Perfect, do you want to add as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Glad that helped, but let Mark have it, I remember getting close to my 10K mark. Very exciting ;-)

Comment: @shelter Sorry! I didn't mean to tread on your toes - and yes - the prospect of 10k is very exciting :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
USER3='USERNAME'
PASSWD3='PASSWORD'
YEAR=$(date "+%G")
WEEK=$(date "+%V")
ftp ...
```

Note that you may need to create the directory before changing there...